# "but no Jonathan"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Todd hears a sound and runs down the hall. **He enters the kitchen and sees a half-eaten pizza, but no Jonathan.** He starts to get worried.

- Is the highlighted sentence idiomatic?
- Is "but no" idiomatic when followed by a name?

Comment: Define "idiomatic". The more *natural* syntax would have you use ***not*** rather than ***no*** in your context, but in the context of "stylised" story-telling language it's fine. But this is effectively off-topic writing advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It worries me when you sit in my head and watch me while I am writing my answers. The fact that you can pull off this feat across the Atlantic Ocean terrifies me.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: But at least I'm being up-front about what I'm thinking! Me, I'm worried that maybe sometimes all I'm doing is slavishly echoing *your* thoughts, which you're diffident about going public with under your own name! :)

Comment: It’s the first time that I have been accused of diffidence. My wife is giggling uncontrollably.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is idiomatic, but it is a somewhat stylized way to say

> he saw two half-eaten pizzas, but not Jonathon.

Comment: More fully expanded, that's *...but [**he did**] not [**see**] Jonathon*. Which I'd say is more obviously "natural" than *...but [**he saw**] no Jonathon.*

Comment: The OP spelt it "Jonathan", which is the traditional spelling, although "Jonathon" is also in use.